# import images from folder according to a list - python

Tags: python, image, list, import

I have a folder named *all* that contains, say, 10000 coloured images named "0.jpg", "1.jpg", "2.jpg", ..., "9998.jpg", "9999.jpg".

I would like to import them in a ndarray for training a neural network; however, I want to import only a subset of them, according to a given list of strings representing their names, for instance:

```
example_list = ['0.jpg','32.jpg','256.jpg','1024.jpg','4096.jpg','9998.jpg']
```

Is it possible to do such a thing in order to save file-reading time? If yes, how? Or is it better to import all the 10000 images in a ndarray nonetheless and then subselecting it?

I hope I have been clear in the explanation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have more memory than their sizes combined..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like

```
files = [open(file, 'r') for file in example_list]
```

work?

Comment: Yes it works, but I made a little modification for inserting the directory, i.e. 
files = [open(".\\{}".format(file), 'r') for file in example_list]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get all the jpgs into a regular python list.

```
jpg_obj_list = []
for jpg in example_list:
    with open("directory/here{}".format(jpg), "r") as f:
        jpg_obj_list.append(f.read())
```

Comment: doesn't anwer the question. you are not filtering by `example_list`.

Comment: What do you mean? I am filtering by example_list. `for jpg in example_list:` it will only use the jpgs that are in the list. And will only put the jpgs that are in the list into the new `jpg_obj_list`